# Connect QGIS to Remote PostgreSQL Server

Tags: qgis, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to connect to my database on a remote server using QGIS. From what I've read I have to edit the `pg_hba.conf` and the `postgresql.conf` files. I think I have edited these files to allow any IP to connect using the password (not very secure but I'll sort that out when I get this issue figured out). I have verified that my parameters in the PostGIS connection tool are correct.

When I try to connect to the database it says theres an error. I'm not sure if I missed a step or if I did anything incorrect, can anyone give me some suggestions on how to get this accomplished?

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::0/0                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
host    replication     all             ::0/0                 md5
```

Versions: QGIS 3.4.14, PostgreSQL 10, pgAdmin 4

OS: Client side -> Windows 10, Server side -> Windows Server 2012

Comment: You said you have an error, but you didn't give it to us.

Comment: Make sure set the line `listen_addresses = '*'  # what IP address(es) to listen on;` in postgresql.conf and to restart the server (note: I strongly discourage against * and 0.0.0.0/0 as it means your DB is an open bar for everybody)

Comment: @JGH I do have listen_addesses set to '*'. I do plan on changing the 0.0.0.0/0, should I change it to the IP of my local desktop?

Comment: yes! (if local), or your router IP or your company IP, and then use a `/32` (or `/24` if your local IP do change a bit). Also if exposed to the web, don't allow `all` users but only specific one(s)

Comment: but these should not prevent you from connecting...

Comment: please add the error and operating systems used client and server side (can vary the answer)

Comment: Added the operating system. The error says "could not connect to server: Connection timed out"

Comment: Check the server firewall then, to open PG port and allow you in.

Comment: it was the server firewall that was causing the issues. I am meeting with the administrators to discuss a plan of attack